# Running Ruby on Rails Application with Amazon Lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have a server running with RoR application on board.

We want to connect this application to S3 bucket upload event. Like if document is uploaded to S3, then we do magic in RoR using file name or current uploaded document.

Do someone have such experience ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Lambda does not support Ruby, but you *can* use it as a go-between for your S3 to RoR use case.

Just write a Lambda function that receives the S3 event, downloads the file using the event, then makes a request to your RoR app with the file attached. From there you can do any processing normally.